# Derivatives: $f_1(x)-f_2(x) = f_1(0)-f_2(0) + \int_0^t [f_1'(u) - f_2'(u)]du$ ??

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I found the following equation in my old math note.

$f_1(x)-f_2(x) = f_1(0)-f_2(0) + \int_0^t [f_1'(u) - f_2'(u)]du$

I am wondering if this is true or if I made a mistake.

If it is a true statement, then I would like to know if this property has its "name" to be called.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which says that $\int_a^b f'(u)~du = f(b)-f(a)$ (provided that the function $f$ is continuously differentiable on the interval $a \le x \le b$).

So in this case you have
$$\int_0^t [f_1'(u) - f_2'(u)]~du ~=~ [f_1(t) - f_2(t)] - [f_1(0) - f_2(0)]$$
which is equivalent to the equation that you have (assuming your $x$ is meant to be a $t$, or vice versa).

So provided the technical requirements on $f_1$ and $f_2$ are satisfied (namely that they're continuously differentiable), it is true by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fundamental theorem of calculus. Consider $g(x) = f_{1}(x) - f_{2}(x)$. Then,

$$g'(x) = f'_{1}(x) - f'_{2}(x)$$

Thus, by fundamental theorem of calculus, we have

$$g(t) - g(0) = \int_{0}^{t} g'(x)dx$$